# Can not build cassandra database stress client by DataStax

Tags: maven, client, cassandra, datastax-java-driver

Im working with my own database cluster with cassandra. I want to try some stress tests with my database, thats why i downloaded DataStax Java-driver for Cassandra.

https://github.com/datastax/java-driver

After I downloaded it, I got to know, that I need Maven to install it. So I downloaded Maven from here and added all necessary paths to the environment.

http://maven.apache.org/download.cgi

Using windows command line I went into the java-driver directory and called

```
mvn install
```

The build was successfull and afterwards I tried to execute the stress jar file in driver-examples/stress/target using command line with

```
 java -jar theJarFile.jar
```

I got the Error:

Failed to load Main-Class manifest attribute from
cassandra-driver-examples-stress-1.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar

How can I run this program?

Background: I worked the first time with maven in this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Better idea will create a maven build project, then import the dependency, configure the cluster details in your project and then run whatever test you want.

Else you can check try this considering the fact that **artifactId** maven-assembly-plugin is not properly done

- Open the stress pom file
- Edit the file

  ```
  <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
          <!--  <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>-->
            <configuration>
                .
                .
                .
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
  ```
- `mvn clean install -e`
- `java -jar target/cassandra-driver-examples-stress-1.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar`

Comment: Do you mean creating an eclipse project for that? I never did that before and why shouldnt I use the command line thing? Should work with this aswell or? Some further description on how to do it would be great.

Comment: Since cassandra-driver-examples-stress-1.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar is not an executable jar file, that's why you are getting that error. Either you set the Main-Class in your from POM file, else use any IDE to run your program.

Comment: Could you give me a description on how to do this in eclipse for example? I would only like to use the stress client, to check the performance of my cluster.

Comment: And if you want to built it via IDE, then simply create a project and then import the modules in your project and run accordingly. SIMPLE!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try following the instructions here for running it?
https://github.com/datastax/java-driver/tree/master/driver-examples/stress

The scripts in bin should work from a cygwin shell, or you could just read the commands in them to run in cmd.exe